# Resolving values in GStringExpression in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to parse Groovy code in Java. I just encountered GStringExpression containing strings and values (Example: `"somestring:$someVariable"` and the value of `$someVariable` is for example `3`). Now if I call `getText` on that expression like so: `((GStringExpression) expression).getText()` it will return the String: `somestring:$someVariable`. How can I resolve the variable so I end up with the following String instead: `somestring:3`?

Thanks

Comment: Just use `toString()`.

Comment: toString() returns something like:
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.GStringExpression@432bfa[strings: [ConstantExpression[somestring:], ConstantExpression[]] values: [org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression@43c5e2[variable: someVariable]]]

Comment: Ah, I see, you're talking about *during the compilation process*. The expression isn't actually evaluated until runtime, so I don't think that it's well-founded to say that `somestring:3` is even correct. Remember that `GString`s have powerful (and sometimes weird) interactions with their evaluation context.

Comment: My goal is to parse the Groovy code with AstBuilder. And when visiting GStringExpression expressions I would like to replace the variable names with their values.

Comment: They don't have values at that point.

Comment: Yes I know but is there a way to resolve those variable expressions?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible, no...  you're trying to do it at compile time, and GStrings don't evaluate until run time... how could it possibly know what the variable's expression WILL be at run time during compile?  Your statement that "someVariable" has a value of 3... how did you know that?

Comment: @user2403221, what is your final goal described in the question?